# Capture and delay javascript onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using a jQuery plugin that adds placeholders to inputs for browsers that do not natively support them and am trying to use it on a form that uses Asp.Net form validation.

On form submit I'm clearing any placeholder values so they are not submitted but validation is not reporting an empty input as it is firing before my input is cleared.

Is there a way of capturing the original validation event on form onsubmit and storing it so that it fires when I wan't it to?

I think this is the method I need to capture.

> onsubmit="javascript:return
>   WebForm_OnSubmit();"

```
    $(function () {

        // capture the original onsubmit event here.

        // Look for forms
        $("form").bind("submit.placeholder", function () {
            // Clear the placeholder values so they don’t get submitted
            var $inputs = $(".placeholder", this).each(clearPlaceholder);

            // call the event here.            

            setTimeout(function () {
                $inputs.each(setPlaceholder);
            }, 10);
        });
    });
```

Comment: use this `$("form").bind("submit", function () {` `.placeholder` is not a custom event and ur messing up the submit event thats probly not triggering the function at all

Comment: @Val: The event is firing, validation occurs on the inputs as other inputs without placeholders in the form are reporting back as invalid. The problem is that the event is firing before the inputs populated with a placeholder value are cleared.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265166/jquery-pause-before-form-submit see if this gives you a better Idea, but you also need to e.preventDefault, then you can use ajax to post data or something, that code is very messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var attrs = $('[onsubmit!=""]').attr('onsubmit');// gets the string of the on submit
$('[onsubmit!=""]').attr('onsubmit','');//remove the onsubmit text

eval(attrs);
```

I wouldnt use eval coz its dangerous (or so some say) but you know up to you.

by the way a placeholder is used on `<input type="text" placeholder="Search" />` on HTML 5